# How can I pass variable from one block function to another function in magento block

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

This is my code:

```
namespace send\sms\Block;

class mobileverification extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function checknumber(){
        $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

        $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->_resources->getTableName('otpp');

        $dates = date("Y-m-d");

        $phone = $_POST["phone"];

        // SELECT DATA
        $sql = "SELECT otp FROM otpp WHERE `phone`='$phone' AND 'dates'='$dates' ORDER BY otp DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result = $connection->fetchall($sql);

        if(!empty($result)){
            // if already exists

            $code = $result[0];
            $otppass = $code['otp'];

            echo $otppass;

        }else{  
            // if already not exists 

            $randcode = rand(100000, 999999);

            $sendotp = $randcode;
            //insert data
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . "(phone, otp, dates) VALUES ('$phone', '$sendotp', '$dates')";

            echo $sendotp;
        }
        $connection->query($sql);

    }

    public function checkotp(){

        $ckotp = $_POST["getotp"];

        if($otppass=$ckotp){
            echo "otp verified";
        }else{
            echo "otp Not verified";
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get value of another function inside **block.php**. use below code.

```
class mobileverification extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public $otppass;

    public function checknumber(){
        $otppass = 123456;
        return $otppass;
    }

    public function checkotp(){
        $otppass = $this->checknumber();
        echo $otppass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. but I'm using rand(0000,9999); for generate otp. If I use return statement and use like $this->checknumber(); the first function repeats again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace send\sms\Block;

class mobileverification extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function checknumber(){
        $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                          ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');  

        $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->_resources->getTableName('otpp');

        $dates = date("Y-m-d");

        $phone = $_POST["phone"];

        $otppass = "";

        // SELECT DATA
        $sql = "SELECT otp FROM otpp WHERE `phone`='$phone' AND 'dates'='$dates' ORDER BY otp DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result = $connection->fetchall($sql); 

        if(!empty($result)){ 
            // if already exists

            $code = $result[0];
            $otppass = $code['otp'];

        } else {  
            // if already not exists 

            $randcode = rand(100000, 999999);

            $otppass = $randcode;
            //insert data
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . "(phone, otp, dates) VALUES ('$phone', '$otppass', '$dates')";

        }
        $connection->query($sql);
        return $sendotp;

    }

    public function checkotp(){

        $otppass = $this->checknumber();
        $ckotp = $_POST["getotp"];

        if($otppass=$ckotp){
            echo "otp verified";
        }else{
            echo "otp Not verified";
        }   
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: but I'm using  rand(0000,9999); for generate otp. If I use return statement and use like $this->checknumber(); the first  function repeats again.

Comment: So can you suggest any other method

Comment: Add your code snippest.

Comment: my code is added

Comment: I have updated my answer